# Why do I get 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch

I've built an autocomplete feature for a small search app using elasticsearch shingles. When I test the analyzer and tokens, everything seems to be set up correctly.

```
    PUT /autocomplete
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    },
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_shingles_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 5,
          "output_unigrams": false
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_shingles_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "autocomplete_shingles_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /autocomplete/_analyze?analyzer=autocomplete_shingles_analyzer&text=2010 toyota camry
```

But then when I go to actually create the index and mapping and use a match query with the _all field, I get 0 results

```
"mappings": {
"suggestions": {
  "_all": {
    "enabled": true,
    "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
  },
  "properties": {
    "makes": {
      "type": "string",
      "include_in_all": true
      },
      "models": {
        "type": "string",
        "include_in_all": true
      },
      "years": {
        "type": "string",
        "include_in_all": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
    PUT /autocomplete/suggestions/_bulk
{"index": {"_id":"1"}}
{"years": ["2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017"]}
{"index": {"_id":"2"}}
{"makes": "Acura", "models": ["Legend Integra NSX Vigor TL RL SLX CL MDX RSX TSX RDX ZDX"]}
{"index": {"_id":"3"}}
{"makes": "Alfa Romeo", "models": ["164 Spider"]}
{"index": {"_id":"4"}}
{"makes": "Aston Martin", "models": ["DB9 Vanquish S DB9 Volante V8 Vantage Vantage DBS Rapide V8 Vantage S V12 Vantage Virage"]}
{"index": {"_id":"5"}}
{"makes": "Alfa Romeo", "models": ["164 Spider"]}
```

Why will this work when I use the validate analyzer API, but when I actually create the index, mapping and query... I get 0 results? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
   {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "2010 acura integra",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** I believe I figured it out, I was using operator: and - which meant all terms had to be in all fields, which wouldn't work. Delete the operator and I get results.  However, in my testing it seems that the multi-match query might be better suited for this because 1)I can boost fields 2) I don't need to use the _all field 3)It seems that it has better options to tweak the query to fine tune it over time, am I on the right track there?

Comment: And what's the query you are using?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, please see the UPDATE, match query on the _all field - is there a better query to use?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `autocomplete_shingles_analyzer` instead of `autocomplete_analyzer` in your `_all` field?

Comment: Zatarain, thanks for the heads up, fixed it but still no results